# Download image to custom notification big view

Tags: android, notifications, imageview

I want to show a dynamically loaded image in the big view part of my notification. My notification has a custom layout for the big view version.

So technically I need to download an image from the web, then show it in a **ImageView** inside a **RemoteViews** object.

The part I'm not able to succeed with is: how to get the downloaded **Bitmap** to show in the **ImageView** of my **RemoteViews** object?

Here is what I tried:

```
Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL(items.get(0).imageUrl);
remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.iv2, "android:src", bm);
```

**and here is the Exception I receive:**

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.example: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `RemoteViews.setBitmap` incorrectly. Instead of calling `android:src` you should use `setImageBitmap`. Alternatively, you can use `RemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap` which will take care of that for you.

Answer (score -2):

RemoteView does not accept ImageView, are you use a ImageView? why do you use Notification.BigPictureStyle instead?

Comment: because I want a customized big view that includes 3 image views, BigPictureStyle give me only 1 picture